# Automating driver installation on Windows XP

Tags: winapi, automation, installation, device-driver

I have a sound card driver and I need to automate the installation of it on windows. Is there any way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question for Server Fault, but many driver install files offer switches that can be used for a silent or unattended install.  You could run the program with the /? switch or contact the device manufacturer for more information.  Once you have that information, you could schedule the command using Scheduled Tasks in XP or the registry (RunOnce key).

Answer (score 1):

Actually you probably want to read the [driver installation section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972910.aspx) on msdn. (For I am not sure what you mean by "automating".)

Answer (score 0):

This question should be asked at server fault.
Anyways, I assume you mean to want it to be installed with your OS.
One way is to slipstream the driver into your Windows OS Installer.
A good guide is:

Using Nlite (Simple) : 
http://www.nliteos.com/

or
(Advanced)
http://unattended.msfn.org/unattended.xp

If not please specify the situation.

Comment: or either through programming

Answer (score 0):

nLite (http://www.nliteos.com/) should have the solution you need.